# Query to retrieve column names

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table Structure:**

[image]

### Scenario:

To retreive name of columns if they are not null so for `Patch_No` = 0.02 would be `Champion` = `Katarina`

This is the query I came up with which unfortunately doesn't work 
**EDIT** The query below gives me Passive, Q, W, E, R so it seems like there is something wrong with the and (passive is not null or [...])

### Query:

```
 SELECT column_name 
from information_schema.columns, patches.champions
 where 
table_name = 'champions'
AND (column_name ='Passive' OR column_name='Q' OR column_name ='W' OR column_name='E' or            column_name='R')
AND (Passive is not null or Q is not null or W is not null or E is not null or R is not null)
AND Patch_No = '0.02'
AND Champion = 'Katarina'
```

I tried to just test for Passive just for this patch and champion and it always gives me 5 passives like it doesn't take Patch_No and Champion restrictions into consideration

**EDIT2**

```
select isc.COLUMN_NAME, c.* 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc, patches.champions c
where TABLE_NAME = 'champions' 
AND Patch_No = 0.02
AND Champion = 'Katarina'

and (
    (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'Passive' and c.Passive is not null)
    or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'Q' and c.Q is not null)
    or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'W' and c.W is not null)
    or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'E' and c.E is not null)
    or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'R' and c.R is not null)
)
order by
     c.ID
```

Comment: What am I missing - passive is not null when patch_no = 0.02, so you should have 3 rows - passive,w and e?

Comment: Try my Query with column_name ='Passive' associated with Passive is not null. I think you need to specify it that way.

Comment: Passive is not null... what am I missing?

Comment: your way gave me this whole table of results http://i.imgur.com/rX1UZLK.png

Comment: When I execute my query it gives 3 rows - 1 each for passive,w and e. can you just run it exactly as it is after replacing my table name with yours?

Comment: check the EDIT2 it gives me the same result as i posted on imgur

Comment: Check your data for those "empty" columns in the image above... are they NULL? or is there a "space" or "tab" or empty string character in there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

NOTE that in the where clause I have removed the quotes from comparison for patch_no on the assumption that patch_no was a numeric datatype. if it is in fact a string you will need to put them back in.

```
select isc.COLUMN_NAME, c.* 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc, patches.champions c
where TABLE_NAME = 'SO_27769554' 
AND Patch_No = .02
AND Champion = 'Katrina'

and (
        (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'pasive' and c.pasive is not null)
        or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'q' and c.q is not null)
        or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'w' and c.w is not null)
        or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'e' and c.e is not null)
        or (isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'r' and c.r is not null)
    )
order by
    c.id
```

Comment: I seriously have trouble to understand any part of this query what is isc and what is c and table name SO_027769554

Comment: @higeat - They are alias names for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS & patches.champions respectively. 'SO_27769554' is my bad, replace it with Champions as in your original Query

Comment: Could you check my Edit i'm pretty close

Answer (score 0):

So this is what actually worked out for me I mostly took code from G B thanks for help!

```
SELECT column_name 
from information_schema.columns, patches.champions
where 
table_name = 'champions'
AND ((column_name ='Passive' and Passive!='')
or (column_name='Q' and Q!='')
or (column_name='W' and W!='')
or (column_name='E' and E!='')
or (column_name='R' and R!='')

)

 AND Patch_No = '0.02'
AND Champion = 'Katarina'
```